Best way to map Airports, Harbours and Trainstations in Overpass-Turbo
I'm new to Overpass and I am trying to find a convenient way to map all major Airports, Harbours and Trainstations (not necessarily in the same query)
But I also want a kind of overseeable global map thats not stuffed too full.
For airports I had some success by filtering for international ones:
nwr["aerodrome:type"="international"] ({{bbox}});

But I noticed that this made it so that in England there was not a single airport mapped.
How can I  approach a global search like this?

If you're unsure about tagging in OpenStreetMap, you might want to discuss this topic on an osm community site, such as https://community.openstreetmap.org/c/help-and-support/7/none

You can find international airports by searching ways with tag "aerodrome"="international":
way["aerodrome"="international"] ({{bbox}});

Here's an example:


The question is, what is the characteristic of a major port or station.

A reality criterion could be the frequency of traffic at a station. But this is not noted in Openstreetmap.
Especially for a harbour could be used the number of traffic lines to a station.
For airports, the number of runways could also be a criterion.
For airports, it can certainly be the tag aerodrome=international, as used by you and TomazicM.
As an indicator for the relevance of a port or station could be their size. But  in Overpass does not the output size of area.
Based on this, the length of the boundary of a station could be an indicator. There is a function in Overpass for providing of the circumference of areas.
And other features? ...

This check the circumference and for tagged international connections, for ways as well as for relations as area:
[timeout: 10];
(
  wr[aeroway=aerodrome] [landuse!=military] (if:length()>10000) ({{bbox}}); //check of circumference 
  wr["aerodrome"="international"] ({{bbox}});
);
out geom;

@ Overpass
Also it would be possible to check for at least 2 runways. But in this case that doesn't provide additional helpful results:
[timeout:300];
wr[aeroway=aerodrome][landuse!=military]({{bbox}});
foreach -> .setOuter {
  .setOuter; map_to_area -> .areaOuter;
  .setOuter;
  way[aeroway=runway](if:t["length"]>2500)(area.areaOuter) -> .setInners;
  if (setInners.count(ways) > 1) {
    (.setOuterExtract; .setOuter;) -> .setOuterExtract;
  }
}
.setOuterExtract;
out geom;

@ Overpass
Furthermore, this calculation is very resource-intensive because the area consists of a lot of points and therefore also takes a very long time.

In the next example major train stations shall be selected. For that, the number of platforms shall be a criterion. First, all possible train stations are searched for. In some train stations are small buildings also tagged as train stations. We assume that relevant train stations also have more than just one additional tag of information, this is an additional criterion with count_tags. Furthermore the length of border is a limitation.
Then it looks for the number of platforms which are there. The map_to_area method would be good for that. But with a larger bounding box, the search needs a long time, as described before. For this reason, the area is in approximation formed differently. It simply takes only any one point of train station and searches within a fixed radius of it (here 400 m). This search is obvious faster and uses therefore fewer resources. 4 platforms are choosed as minimum. Of course, alle values can be modified according to other requirements.
[timeout:300];
(
  wr[building=train_station] (if:length()>100) (if:(count_tags())>2) ({{bbox}});
  // wr[public_transport=station] (if:(count_tags())>1) ({{bbox}}); 
);
  
foreach -> .setOuter {
  .setOuter;
  if (u(type()=="relation")) {way(r);};   // in case of relation provide also a way
  node(w:2) -> .setNode;                  // get any node
  .setOuter;
  wr[public_transport=platform] (around.setNode:400) -> .setInners;
  if (setInners.count(ways) > 4) {
    (.setOuterExtract; .setOuter;) -> .setOuterExtract;  // add the found set to the total set
  }
}
(
  .setOuterExtract;
  wr[building=train_station] (if:length()>300) ({{bbox}});  // add further criterion
);
out geom;

@ Overpass
